# Is there some generally accepted "standard bookkeeping file format"?

Tags: software, bookkeeping

I have my self-coded bookkeeping database and manager. Now I want to make an "export" feature in order to be able to hand my data to the government if they make me do it (if the other option is getting put into a cage). I'm thinking of a simple CSV dump with some basic fields, but as easy as it would be for me to do that, I want to make sure that it will be an accepted format.

Is CSV good for this? And if so, what exact fields are expected to be present? And do they want the sums formatted in a certain way, etc.?

Perhaps there is some de facto bookkeeping software which likes a specific format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The de facto format is [Open Financial Exchange (OFX)](https://www.ofx.org/). It is supported by most freeware and paidware bookkeeping/accounting software.